# How to reach Amazon's customer care service?

Tags: purchase, customer-service

As some of you like me would have experienced, if you encounter any exceptional issues with purchases on Amazon, for which you need to contact the customer care service of Amazon, you seem to hit a wall. This is because Amazon's website seem to prevent you from accessing the contact information of its customer care service right away. Also, if you search on the web about this, there isn't really any clear consensus about how to reach Amazon's customer care service. This is especially difficult in non-US countries, as there is a flood of information regarding US's amazon.com, but hardly anything for Amazon's service in non-US countries.

On the Amazon's website, the options that are supposed to take you to the customer care service will often either take you back to your order information, or move you in circles thorough their FAQ pages. In my own experience, and I would imagine in others too, this is truly frustrating you to the point that you'd want to give up on troubleshooting your purchases.

To circumvent this, what I am asking is a very simple question: How to reach Amazon's customer care service?

I think this question is relevant to this channel. So putting this issue up for discussion here in this channel might be helpful for some.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance.

Answer (score 1):

For amazon.ca, after spending quite a lot of time, I finally figured out how to reach Amazon's customer care service. I hope this information would be helpful to someone.

The solution is very counter-intuitive.

1. Start from the **Contact us** page : https://www.amazon.ca/gp/help/customer/contact-us/ref=cu_surl.
   I got to this page by simply searching "Contact us" on Amazon.ca's home page.
2. Counter-intuitively, select **Non-order related** option, even though your query might be related to an order.

[image]

3. Select **Unknown or incorrect charges** and **Authorization charge**.

[image]

Then finally there would be an access to the phone number or option to chat. From my experience, the live chat option was much quicker than the phone option.

[image]